# Find out what instance of SFCC do I have

Tags: account, sandbox, instance, commerce-cloud, type

How can I find out what instance of SFCC do I have?

I am very new to SFCC and I was provided with the account of SFCC by my employer.

So, now I want to learn the SFCC. For this I go to the [documentation](https://documentation.b2c.commercecloud.salesforce.com/DOC1/index.jsp) - Getting Started for Developers - Install or Update UX Studio. And here I find out that depending on the instance type which I was provided I should pick the correct link for the Eclipse plugin installation. There are three options: **Sandbox**, **PIG** and **Extended Preview or Early Access Sandbox**.

I suspect that I have a **Sandbox**, but I am not absolutely sure. How could I check that? Thank you.

I have an account over here: https://xchange.demandware.com.

Comment: There is not much difference between these versions of the eclipse plugin. You can use either one of them with a sandbox.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The Business Manager backend of the instances have color-coded headers:

- Sandbox = grey
- Development = green
- Staging = blue
- Production = red

[image: Development Header Screenshot]
[image: Staging Header Screenshot]

Additionally on the top left you can see the instance name written (above your site dropdown)

Finally, you can usually tell by the hostname of the instance. Production, Staging, and Development all have the instance type in their URLs eg:

```
production-realmname-customername.demandware.net
staging-realmname-customername.demandware.net
development-realmname-customername.demandware.net
```

Typically sandboxes will have `dev` in their name, eg:

```
dev01-realmname-customername.demandware.net
```

There are also new DX sandboxes which use a different convention where `realmid` is a 4-character code that identifies your realm followed by a numeric identifier for the sandbox:

```
realmid-001.sandbox.us01.dx.commercecloud.salesforce.com
```

Staging, Development, and Production belong to the PIG (Primary Instance Group)

Sandboxes are part of the SIG (Secondary Instance Group)

The various instance types are described here: https://documentation.b2c.commercecloud.salesforce.com/DOC1/topic/com.demandware.dochelp/GettingStarted/Demandwareinstances.html

UX Studio should be connected to your sandbox environment for development.